How is Nationality Principle applied in practice?
I was very surprised to see some people thinking that once they step out of their country of citizenship its laws no longer apply to them.
It is my understanding that the concept of citizenship includes jurisdiction of the country over its citizens, whether they're on its territory or not ("The Nationality Principle"). Routinely, countries demand extradition of their citizens for criminal offenses, and prosecute citizens for crimes committed outside their borders.
Apparently the concept is much more controversial than I thought. So, how is it really being applied, and is it uniform or different countries see this differently?
Note: I'm asking about a country exercising sovereignty over its own citizens, not other countries recognizing that sovereignty. I'm well aware that extradition requests don't have to be granted. A good example would be an X citizen in country Y does what a country X considers a crime and perfectly legal in country Y, yet X citizens could still be prosecuted for that. Like this case:

Russian human rights activists said while living in the US she had made a single transfer of $51.80 on the first day of Russia's full-scale invasion of Ukraine on 22 February 2022. The FSB is thought to have discovered the transaction on her phone.


"Routinely, countries demand extradition of their citizens for criminal offenses, and prosecute citizens for crimes committed outside their borders." Extradition is not a citizenship based inquiry. It usually applies to crimes committed by both citizens and non-citizens in its own borders. Prosecution of citizens for crimes committed outside a country's borders is a rare exception and only applies to select crimes.

@ohwilleke: I found a couple of examples off the top of my head: Here's one - crime committed in SA, extradited to Russia. Here's another - crime committed in Russia, extradited to the US. The second one seems to be more relevant to the last of Jen's points, though - crimes committed against US citizens, not by them.

The larger context is that a country has criminal law jurisdiction over crimes committed in a country or directed at a country. Some countries recognize "universal jurisdiction" for crimes against humanity (e.g. Spain). There is very limited extraterritorial jurisdiction over citizens on citizenship alone (tax fraud, child prostitution). But, the point is that citizenship isn't relevant to extradition in most cases, and that the nationality principle is the exception and not the rule.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_sex_tourism#Extraterritorial_jurisdiction for a case where many countries will indeed (try to) prosecute people for certain acts committed abroad.

I'm asking about a country exercising sovereignty over its own citizens, not other countries recognizing that sovereignty. That may be a distinction without a difference. Countries also frequently try to prosecute non-citizens for various reasons, all the way to claiming universal jurisdiction for specific crimes. If that claim is not widely recognized, it's not “sovereignty” or a principle, it's just a unilateral claim and a conflict of norms.

Most laws do not apply extraterritorially
There is a general presumption against the extraterritorial application of a law. All legislation is prima facie territorial. Only where a contrary intent appears in the statute does legislation apply extraterritorially. See American Banana, Aramco, and more recently, Morrison v. National Australia Bank, 561 U.S. 247 (2010). Similarly, in Canada, see Society of Composers, Authors and Music Publishers of Canada v. Canadian Assn. of Internet Providers, 2004 SCC 45, para. 55.
The rationale for the presumption is based in comity at international law.
On that understanding, there are five generally recognized (although still contested to various degrees) grounds on which extraterritorial application of a statute is proper (and again, only if the clear intent is expressed in the statute). See the Restatement (Third) of Foreign Relations Law, or a similar listing in Danielle Ireland-Piper, "Extraterritorial Criminal Jurisdiction: Does the Long Arm of the Law Undermine the Rule of Law" (2012) 13(1) Melbourne Journal of International Law 122

to a country's own citizens, wherever they are located (the "nationality" principle you're asking about)
to activities with a substantial territorial effect (the "effects" principle)
for national security purposes (the "protective" principle)
over activities universally recognized as crimes against humanity (the "universality" principle)
where the victim of the act is a national of the state asserting jurisdiction (also known as the "passive nationality principle")

Those are the circumstances where a nation can1 have their law apply extraterritorially. Whether any given law does apply extraterritorially depends on the expressed intent in the law itself.
Some examples where states have relied on nationality to exert jurisdiction extraterritorially are:

Canada provides for extraterritorial application of its criminal law for offences committed by Canadian citizens on the international space station, as well as for hostage taking, treason against Canada, bigamy, torture, sexual offenses against children, war crimes, and genocide (this is not a complete list, but meant to indicate the kinds of offences where Canada asserts its jurisdiction extraterritorially over its citizens).
The United States asserts its jurisdiction extraterritorially through criminal laws relating to air travel, customs, spacecraft, and human trafficking and sex offences (this is also not a complete list).

Each the several states of the US can also criminalize extraterritorial conduct of their citizens, as long as the state has a legitimate interest and there is no conflict with federal law (Skiriotes v. Florida, 319 US 69 (1941)). Other than what was ceded to the union, the state retains "the status of a sovereign."

1. Here I mean "can" in the sense of it would be acceptable to other nations generally; in another sense, of course any nation can do anything.

You might want to add that as a matter of policy, where a crime is one of dual criminality, a country will not usually assert extraterritoriality if the perpetrator has been subjected to the criminal process of the host state. So, if a French person commits a terrorist act against a UK person in Germany, if Germany prosecutes, the others won't.

The USA also asserts its jurisdiction by putting diplomatic pressure on foreign countries. The CIA once kidnapped a person in Italy. The Italian police prevented the knidnap and arrested the CIA agents. Italy intended to presecute the agents. But the USA forced Italy to release them. Back in the USA all charges were dropped. So the CIA apparently has some sort of extraterritorial immunity.

@M.Wind Caving to diplomatic pressure doesn't equate to legal immunity. Similarly, in the recent prisoner swap between Russia and Western countries, neither side giving up prisoners in the swap claimed that the prisoners given up were immune.

@ohwilleke: "neither side giving up prisoners in the swap claimed that the prisoners given up were immune" – Quite the opposite, actually. The German Federal Prosecutor as well as the Justice Department have made it very clear that if Vadim Nikolayevich Krasikov were ever to return Germany, he would have to serve out the rest of his life sentence in full. In fact, the German Federal Prosecutor did not even allow the exchange in the first place, the Justice Secretary had to assert his superiority and order the Federal Prosecutor to affect the deportation.

@DaleM It's ironic you chose an example involving France and terrorism because France has considerably hardened its anti-terrorism legislation and a very limited interpretation of the ne bis in idem principle. It would depend on the specifics of course but in such a scenario, a prosecution in France does not seem out of the question, the only limit set by the courts is that any (prison) sentence served abroad will be subtracted from the French sentence at the end of the procedure.

france claims an extensive extraterritorial application of its criminal laws.
The relevant statute is articles 113-1 to 113-14 of the penal code. French criminal law is applicable to:

anything occuring over French territory (113-2), ships (113-3) and aircrafts (113-4) operating under French flag
any felony committed by French citizens anywhere, or any misdemeanor when committed in a country where it is also illegal (113-6) [the limit between "felony" (crime) and "misdemeanor" (délit) is whether the maximum applicable imprisonment term is above or below 10 years] which has not been prosecuted abroad (113-9)
anything electronic that had targets in French territory (113-2-1), or anything targeting a French citizen if it can carry a jail sentence (113-7) and has not been prosecuted abroad (113-9)
any crime with a maximum sentence of five years in prison or more, even committed by a non-citizen outside of French territory with no French targets, when the author is in French custody and the extradition request was refused due health reasons or because the requesting country would not guarantee a fair trial, would prosecute for political reasons, or might impose an unconscionable sentence [= death penalty or corporal punishment] (113-8-1)
plus a bunch of claims of jurisdiction for large-scale international criminal activity (counterfeiting, terrorism, etc.) which I will not bother detailing here.

You could say "laws no longer apply" to a French citizen abroad after reading 113-6, but really, you can smoke weed in Amsterdam and procure prostitution in Hamburg and that is about it. The real difference is in practice rather than theory - if a French citizen murders someone in a country with a weak state apparatus and tense diplomatic relations with France, then flees back to Paris, French courts have jurisdiction but the prosecutor will have difficulties preparing a case.

(+1) It might be interesting to note that article 113-6 mainly exists because France doesn't extradite its own citizens. Ultimately, it's not that extensive and quite different in spirit to what the OP is asking about because it's not a blanket claim of “sovereignty” based on citizenship but rather a way to close gaps created by other rules. In practice, it's also (or mostly?) used against people who are already in France or even in custody, not so much as a basis for extradition requests. 113-9 and especially 113-8-1 follow from the same logic and are not connected to citizenship at all.

Every country is free to decide who its laws apply to. The most common rule is “any crime committed in the country” by whoever against whoever. If everyone followed that rule then any crime would be prosecuted exactly once.
The USA for example adds “US citizen committing bribery abroad” and “US citizen murdering another US citizen abroad” (that’s probably not a complete list), and other countries can add other crimes.
PS The question could be misunderstood. Say a German citizen moves to Italy. Most crimes according to German law that he could commit would be crimes according to Italian law as well, so he is not allowed to do these things - because of Italian law.

I assume that you mean "committing bribery abroad" and not "commuting bribery abroad", unless they are bribing transit officials. And, I don't think that there is a general statute allowing U.S. citizens to be prosecuted for murdering other U.S. citizens abroad. If I get drunk in an Italian bar (I'm a U.S. citizen) and happen to murder a U.S. tourist there, I don't think that any U.S. murder statute applies. There a some cases where a murder of a U.S. citizen abroad (by anyone) is within the scope of extraterritorial U.S. laws, but additional conditions (e.g. terrorism) are required.

The US actually happily prosecutes bribery committed by non-US citizens as well.

@ohwilleke are you sure about this? See here: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1119

@Relaxed, is that in general, or let’s say a company with a US and a French employee decides to bribe someone, the US employee decides it is too risky, and leaves it to the French colleague?

@gnasher729 The Justice department needs some legal theory to connect the case to the US, the FCPA does not establish universal jurisdiction on bribery cases but in practice, it's much more general than your example and certainly not limited to US citizens. This case is especially famous in France but it is not the only one.

@littleadv Good catch. I stand corrected.
